# Can't get JPEG compression to work with ImageIO

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I wrote a test to see how setCompressionQuality() effects the file size and quality. However all the files created are the same size indicating that perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I've looked at many guides online on how to do this and other questions on stackoverflow and I still can't spot my mistake. Any ideas. SSCCE below.

Background: Why am I using JPEG for screenshots!!? Yes I realize PNG is the tool for the job, but I'm trying to implement a "low quality" mode on a custom in-house remote desktop solution running over a low bandwidth link, the quality really doesn't matter as long as the user can sort of see what is going on.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class ImageCompressionJpg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit
                .getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("screen.standard.jpg"));

        // JPEGs, different qualities 0 - 1
        for (float quality = 0; quality <= 1; quality += 0.2) {
            ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) ImageIO
                    .getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            param.setCompressionQuality(quality);
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(
                    String.format("screen.%.1f.jpg", quality)));
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            writer.write(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a different `write()` overload and pass an `IIOImage` and your custom params to it:

```
ImageWriter writer  = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(
    new File(String.format("screen.%.1f.jpg", quality))));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
writer.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the ImageParams into the ImageWriter

```
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```